# Show that if $\sigma = 0$ then every nonzero solution $x(t)$ is a periodic solution. Show that if $\sigma > 0$ then as $t \to \infty$, $x(t) \to 0$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

The full problem reads:
Suppose that the motion of a mass $m$ is described by the nonlinear differential equation $m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\alpha x^3 - \sigma \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^3$ where $\alpha >0$ and $\sigma \geq 0$.

(a) Show that if $\sigma = 0$ then every nonzero solution $x(t)$ of the system is a periodic solution.

(b) Show that if $\sigma > 0$ then as $t \to \infty$, $x(t) \to 0$.

I have attempted part (a) by setting $\dot x = y$ and thus $\dot y = \ddot x = \frac{-\alpha}{m} x^3$. But then the problem I have run into is that there are no equilibrium points where $x(t) > 0$, the only one that exists for this situation is $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

So my question is: how do I go about showing that every nonzero solution here is periodic when I can't use something like Poincare-Bendixson. Any tips on part (b) are also welcome. Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the dynamic system

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot x & = & y\\
\dot y & = & -\alpha x^3
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\alpha x^3\dot x & = & \alpha x^3 y\\
y\dot y & = & -\alpha x^3 y
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow \left(\frac 14\alpha x^4+\frac 12 y^2\right)' = 0
$$

hence the orbits are described by the curves

$$
\frac 14\alpha x^4+\frac 12 y^2 = C_0
$$

[image]

characterizing a center. Attached a stream plot for $\alpha = 1, \sigma = 0\;$. The same procedure can be used to show that when $\sigma > 0\;\;$ those orbits collapse to zero with time.

NOTE

$$
\left(\frac 14\alpha x^4+\frac 12 y^2\right)' = -\sigma y^4 < 0,\;\;\forall y \ne 0
$$

Considering now $\sigma=\alpha=1\;$ we have the stream plot

[image]

MATHEMATICA scripts attached

`alpha = 1;
sigma = 0;
StreamPlot[{y, -alpha x^3 - sigma y^3}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
alpha = 1;
sigma = 1;
StreamPlot[{y, -alpha x^3 - sigma y^3}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: How did you generate those plots?

Comment: @copper.hat  Using the MATHEMATICA commands included at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$

Comment: I like how streamplot fails to reproduce real trajectories in case of non-hyperbolic equilibrium: probably I will use this as future illustration for such problem. By the way, does the problem go away if you tweak streamplot parameters?

Comment: streamplot does not take into account qualitative aspects of the systems it handles. It hardly considers numerical aspects which can lead, in some cases, to erroneous interpretations.

Comment: @Cesareo I know, but this is a reason why it is instructive. It tells why relying only on numerics can lead to incorrect conclusion. I've also remembered a pretty popular question where the hypothesis based on streamplot pictures turned out to be false.

Comment: @Evgeny You are plenty of reason.

Comment: @Cesareo I'll take that as a compliment :)

Comment: @Evgeny That was my intention.